VS Code C# Extension Error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server
Yesterday my VS Code (latest version) started throwing this error when loading the C# extension. Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server..
More details from the terminal window below.
Activating C# + C# Dev Kit...
[Error - 10:16:25 AM] Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '


I have been on the pre-release track with this (to support .NET MAUI Hot Reload) but I have tried older versions of c# extension and c# dev kit extension.
I have uninstalled, deleted the .vscode folder, delete the folder from Roaming\Code, instlaled the system version...
I have reviewd the .js file referenced in the console error and can't see anything wrong, but maybe I am not reading it correctly.
Any ideas?
